# Symfony PHP - Using service within another service

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, autowired, symfony4

I have a Symfony 4 app that calls a database service from within a session service.

The database service has a `__construct` methods that grabs db credentials from `services.yaml`

**DB Service**

```
namespace App\Services;

class Database {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct($host, $name, $user, $pass){

        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$name) or die('error: cannot connect');
    }

    //...
}
```

**config/services.yaml**

```
services:
    App\Services\Database:
        arguments:
            $host: '1.2.3.4.5'
            $name: 'database_name'
            $user: 'username'
            $pass: 'password'
```

I am using this service in a Sessions service used by a Login controller.

**Login Controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Services\Database;
use App\Services\Session;

// ...
// ...
    if($login_valid){
        //...
        $session = new Session();
        $session->create();
    }
```

**Session Service**

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\Database;

class Session {

    private $DB;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->DB = new Database();  // ** ERROR **
    }

    public function create(){

        $this->DB->insert('a new session'); // (pseudo-code)
    }
    //...
}
```

This throws an error when setting the DB service instance in the Session service. The error is as follows:
[image]

The `__construct` method for DB is called which takes the 4 arguments (defined globally in `services.yaml`) which I am not providing when instantiating the DB service inside the Session service.

But this is never the case when I instantiate the DB service this way directly in a controller.

Moreover, isnt one of the benefits of using `__construct` with service arguments set in `services.yaml` to avoid having to pass these arguments every time?

Symfony knows to fire `__construct` when the DB service is called, and the arguments it needs are set right there in `services.yaml` - what gives?

Comment: You need to dependency inject `Session` that has `Database` injected via a constructor as well. Ideally, you should now use `new` anywhere here by yourself.

Comment: Use dependency injection.

Comment: err: `should noW use` -> `should noT use`

Comment: @zerkms why is it bad practice to use `new`?

Comment: @yevg I did not say it's a bad practice, I'm just saying that in this very case you don't need to instantiate anything manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short you need to use dependency injection.

You are correct that by registering the `Database` class arguments in `services.yml`, Symfony is able to inject these values during instantion. However, this is only done automatically when using the dependency injection container.

You will need to use this in both your `LoginController` and in your `Session` service.

**LoginController**

```
namespace App\Controller

use App\Services\Session;

class LoginController
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

**Session**

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Services\Database;

class Session 
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function create(){

        $this->db->insert('a new session'); // (pseudo-code)
    }
}
```